# Sine is algebraically less than cosine in given interval.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Prove that Sine is algebraically less than Cosine for any angle between $2n\pi-\dfrac{3\pi}{4}$ and $2n\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

My attempts:

$\sin \bigg(-\dfrac{3\pi}{4}\bigg)=\cos \bigg(-\dfrac{3\pi}{4}\bigg)=-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Now when moved further  $\sin$ will starts increasing in magnitude (till $\dfrac{-3\pi}{2}$) and $\cos$ will decrease, hence because they are in $3^{rd}$ quadrant $\implies\sin<\cos$.

Now if we enter  $4^{th}$ quadrant $\cos>0$ and $\sin<0$ till $2\pi$ $\implies\cos>\sin$.

Now if we cross $4^{th}$ quadrant $\sin\uparrow$, from $0$ and $\cos\downarrow$, from $1$, and becomes euqals at $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$, will imply $\cos>\sin$ till $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$. Hence the results.

But is there any way to do this with pure algebra, without these intuitions.

Please help.

Comment: You've basically done the work, which implies $n=0$

Comment: "algebraically less" as opposed to what other sort of less?

Comment: @LanierFreeman yes we can add $2n\pi$ which brings your revolving line again at that position, so for ease of calculation neglected.

Comment: You're right I was just going for the trivial answer

Comment: @Chappers like $2<3$ but $-2>-3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cos t-\sin t=\sqrt2\cos\left(t+\dfrac\pi4\right)$$ which needs to be $$>0$$

$$\implies2m\pi-\dfrac\pi2<t+\dfrac\pi4<2m\pi+\dfrac\pi2$$ where $m$ is any integer

Alternatively, $$\cos t-\sin t=\sqrt2\sin\left(\dfrac\pi4-t\right)$$

So we need $$2r\pi<\dfrac\pi4-t<2r\pi+\pi$$ where $r$ is any integer

Answer (score 0):

Interpret an angle  as the curvilinear abscissa of a point on the trigonometric circle. These values correspond to the half-circle which is *below* the line $y=x$, i.e. one has  $y<x$.