# Proving that sine is algebraically less than cosine for any angle between $2n\pi-3\pi/4$ and $2n\pi+\pi/4$, for integer $n$

Tags: trigonometry

I've been studying trigonometry from SL Loney. In examples xviii there is a question no 31, which says

> Prove that the sine is algebraically less than the cosine for any angle between $2n\pi-3\pi/4$ and $2n\pi+\pi/4$, where $n$ is any integer.

I know it seems quite logical by just watch the sine and cosine graph, but I don't know how to prove this. Anyone please provide me the proof.

Comment: For starters, you can turn this into simpler problem by shifting the angle to $0$. By the transformation $ x \to x-2n \pi$. Or you can solve it for $\frac{-3\pi}{4}$ to $ \frac{\pi}{4}$ then shift domain of function by add $2n \pi$ to angle arguements

Comment: For the positive side, we can note that the function $f(x) = \sin x - \cos x$ has a root $ x= \frac{\pi}{4}$ and $f(-1)$ meaning that in $\left[0, \frac{\pi}{4} \right]$, $ f(x) < 0$. For the negative side, you can use the fact that $sin(x) < \cos(x)$ because $sin$ is negative on the negative angle till $ - \frac{3\pi}{4}$

Comment: This question has an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2375816/sine-is-algebraically-less-than-cosine-in-given-interval?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

### Hint

[image]

$${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This is pretty obvious. But I wanted the proof which I got now. I have mentioned in my question that it's obvious from graph that the sine is algebraically less than the cosine for the particular interval. By the way thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Rajiv The purpose of my answer was to provide intuition for constructing an algebraic solution. More specifically, it could help one consider the regions where $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are increasing and decreasing and the important points to consider. This can also be done from a graph, but I hoped that the unit circle made this a bit more explicit.

Comment: I am totally understand and agree that the unit circle presents more clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

If $\cos\alpha=\sin\alpha=c$, then $\sin(x-\alpha)=c(\sin x-\cos x)$.

So choose $\alpha=\pi/4$, so that $c=1/\sqrt 2$ is positive; and we get that the sign of $\sin x-\cos x$ is the same as the sign of $\sin(x-\pi/4)$.

Therefore $\sin x$ is less than $\cos x$ (I don't know what "algebraically less" means here) whenever $\sin(x-\pi/4)$ is negative, i.e. whenever $x-\pi/4\in((2n-1)\pi,2n\pi)$ for some integer $n$.